# Change in Query Param not refreshing the route

Tags: ember.js

I have set the queryParam setting in the route to refresh the model if the query param changes. However when the query param changes `setupController` is not called. Any idea why this is happening?

```
export default Route.extend({
  queryParams: {
    id: {
      refreshModel: true
    }
  },

  setupController(controller) {
    controller.start(); // fetches data synchronously from api
  }
});
```

// Solution thanks to alptugd's reply

```
export default Route.extend({
  queryParams: {
    id: {
      refreshModel: true
    }
  },

  model() {
    // Returning a new array/object/value everytime the hook is called, causes the 
    // setupController hook to be called.
    return [];
  }

  setupController(controller) {
    controller.start(); // fetches data synchronously from api
  }
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`refreshModel` forces the route to `refresh` and as expected you should expect  `beforeModel`, `model`, `afterModel`, and `setupController` hooks to run. However; there is a minor difference for `setupController` hook:

Take a look at the comment for `refresh` method of Ember's `route.js` in the [source code](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/v2.17.0/packages/ember-routing/lib/system/route.js#L1144) or [relevant API documentation](https://emberjs.com/api/ember/2.17/classes/Route/methods/refresh?anchor=refresh). Both say:

"Refresh the model on this route and any child routes, firing the `beforeModel`, `model`, and `afterModel` hooks in a similar fashion to how routes are entered when transitioning in from other route. The current route params (e.g. `article_id`) will be passed in to the respective model hooks, and if a different model is returned, `setupController` and associated route hooks will re-fire as well."

This means; in order for the `setupController` to trigger in case a `refresh` occurs; a different model should be returned from the `model` hook. In your case; you do not have any model `hook`; hence `setupController` will not be called upon `id` param value change.

By the way; it is a good practice to call super method in case you override `setupController` hook since its sole purpose is to save the `model` property to the `controller`. Take a look at the [API](https://emberjs.com/api/ember/2.17/classes/Route/methods/setupController?anchor=setupController) for a detailed explanation regarding this case.

Comment: Thanks! Returning an empty array from the model hook caused the model hook to return a different value each time it's called which in turn caused the setupController to be called. It worked! Although seems like ember is doing a redundant optimization here since we have glimmer diffing.
Btw, I am not calling super intentionally since I am setting the model synchronously in the controller.

Comment: @dorindo glad that worked for you. "I am setting the model synchronously in the controller." it is OK if you know what you are doing. Ember can be tricky from time to time. I just wanted to warn to prevent further problems. good luck. thanks for the up-vote by the way.